# Gradle circular dependency, force ignore

Tags: gradle, build, circular-dependency

I am trying to create a service registry where all the modules are added as compile(project(*..*)). The service registry module expose an unified function to call any function from any module. This is to reduce the direct coupling between two modules and to provide a proper separation of concern. To call any function from any module one can add dependency of service-registry as project and get the function. But if we do that the project has circular dependency.

Is there a way I can force gradle to ignore circular dependency,

```
project root
    project A
    -- compile(project(':SR'))
    project B
    -- compile(project(':SR'))
    project SR
    -- compile(project(':A')
    -- compile(project(':B')
```

I will be moving the dependencies to nexus and use versioning, but in initial phase it would be great if somehow I can force gradle not to do so.
Can it be done by doing some condition as

```
if(calling_project_name!=root) compile(project(':A'),project(':B'))exclude(project(':calling project name')
```

is it possible to do? Other suggestions are also welcome.
I am using gradle 2.7.

Comment: was you solve this ?

Comment: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062841/how-to-resolve-circular-dependency-in-gradle)