# Multi-project error dependencies with gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

When i add   `compile(project(":engine"))` to social project, i got error and i dont know why. But when i add   `compile(project(":social"))` to engine project everything working
settings.gradle.kts

```
rootProject.name = "projectdc"
include("engine", "social", "music", "twitch")
```

build.gradle.kts (social project)

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()

}

dependencies {
      compile(project(":engine"))
}
```

When i add this line   `compile(project(":engine"))` i got Error:

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:engine:classes
\--- :engine:compileJava
     +--- :engine:compileKotlin
     |    +--- :engine:jar
     |    |    +--- :engine:classes (*)
     |    |    +--- :engine:compileKotlin (*)
     |    |    \--- :engine:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
     |    |         \--- :engine:classes (*)
     |    \--- :social:jar
     |         +--- :social:classes
     |         |    \--- :social:compileJava
     |         |         +--- :engine:jar (*)
     |         |         +--- :social:compileKotlin
     |         |         |    +--- :engine:jar (*)
     |         |         |    \--- :social:jar (*)
     |         |         \--- :social:jar (*)
     |         +--- :social:compileKotlin (*)
     |         \--- :social:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
     |              \--- :social:classes (*)
     +--- :engine:jar (*)
     \--- :social:jar (*)
```

Comment: the error message is quite clear: you have a circular dependency between `engine` and `social` projects, which is not allowed.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti i dont know what is 'circular dependency"

Comment: find more information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178381/resolve-circular-dependency-in-gradle/58186686#58186686